# ASP Login Control in IIS not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis, authentication

I have developed a web site that utilizes login in control using the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool. I then moved the entire project over to the server that will be hosting the project. I have the site on IIS 7 but when I try to login, I get the error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>   )

I have given the proper permissions to NETWORKSERVICE. It seems from browsing around online that this is a sql server problem. It works fine in VWD Express but not on IIS. I know that the roles,users,permissions are stored in a .mdf but I'm guessing that it's not being accessed correctly.
Does anyone have any insight on this?

Here is my connection string:

> add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GMPL-20130618083445;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-GMPL-20130618083445.mdf"
>         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For reference, this has *nothing* to do with the login control.  The problem is that the application isn't able to access the database.  Either the database isn't running, or the connection string is wrong, or the application can't "see" the database on the network, or the permissions aren't in place, etc.

Comment: @David Thanks for that, I have posted my connection above. How would I be able to tell if the application can or cannot "see" the database from the network?

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to use "LocalDB", which is probably not installed on your server. You probably should be connecting to a regular database, as opposed to LocalDB.

LocalDB is a new kind of SQL Express - seems to be made for development machines rather than for actual servers.

Comment: I've noticed most sites saying that the data source should be Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS. I'm assuming that this refers to some instance of SQL express that I need to connect to?

Comment: It just needs to be some SQL server. If you have a SQL Express instance on your web server, then `.\SQLEXPRESS` is probably ok. If your database is elsewhere, then it would be the server name.

Answer (score 0):

change Connection string to

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.